# How to retrieve the email from gae datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I was using the google datastore and jinja2 for starting off. I am able to add and retrieve string values but when I use the email property as :
email=db.Email
and retrieve it using .email, I get 
class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Email' from the datastore.
How do i get the value of the email instead?

Answer (score 0):

using .email works for me.

python code

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Greeting(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.EmailProperty()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    en = Greeting(author='hellooo', email=db.Email("a@a.com"))
    en.put()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

and get the value like this

```
dev~devchat> x = Greeting.get_by_id(2)
dev~devchat> x.author
u'hellooo'
dev~devchat> x.email
u'a@a.com'
dev~devchat> x.email.ToXml()
u'<gd:email address="a@a.com" />'
```